# OSX El Capitan / disable System Integrity Protection, csrutil is unavailable (to setup ntfs-3g)

Tags: macos, ntfs, data-recovery

Goal: write to NTFS on El Capitan (following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/Coeur/86a18b646a3b78930cf3))

Problem: csrutil is not accessible so I can't disable System Integrity Protection

Question: is it possible to create a boot disc with [these instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/30/create-os-x-el-capitan-boot-install-drive/), add csrutil, and use it to disable SIP?  Or is there something else I can do to disable SIP without completely reinstalling the OS?

Background: this is on a refurbished MacBook Pro
I *believe* it has no recovery partition, but here's the output of `diskutil list` just to make sure:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS OSX                     249.7 GB   disk0s2
```

I *think* they copied a disc image onto the drive rather than installing with an installer, so no recovery partition was created.

When I hold Cmd+R, it doesn't boot into recovery mode, it launches "internet recovery".

*"... Internet Recover will re-install the version of OS X that originally came with the Mac."*
Unfortunately, a version of osx which did not have csrutil.

Within this internet recovery system, I tried running csrutil i.e. **I typed csrutil into the terminal**, but the command was not found.

I tried running csrutil from /Volumes/OSX/usr/bin/csrutil i.e. **not from /usr/bin of the internet recovery system, but rather from the /usr/bin folder of the el capitan system installed on the boot drive**
but it failed with the message

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/Volumes/OSX/usr/bin/csrutil) is code signed with entitlements
dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSDictionary0__
  Referenced from: /Volumes/OSX/usr/bin/csrutil
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
 in /Volumes/OSX/usr/bin/csrutil
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: @Tetsujin the system boots and works fine, the only motivation to boot into recovery was to disable SIP.  Does the question contain all relevant information now or is there still something missing in your eyes?  Thanks

Comment: The rewrite makes far more sense now. Good edit. Previously it sounded like you'd somehow broken recovery whilst doing this task - it's now clear that the recovery partition was simply never there. There's a tool you can use to create one - linked from http://www.macworld.com/article/2602951/mac-gems-recovery-partition-creator-adds-os-x-recovery-to-any-drive.html [the write-up is old, but the app is up to date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.  If you create a boot disc [like this](http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/30/create-os-x-el-capitan-boot-install-drive/), it gives you access to a terminal and csrutil, which you can use to disable SIP.